# I'd like to inject Repositories container at controller using typedi

Tags: typescript, express, dependency-injection, undefined, typedi

Im trying use @Inject from typedi but it is not working while Container.get does.

im using node 18.16.0

typedi 0.10.0

it throw this error:

```
 throw new cannot_inject_value_error_1.CannotInjectValueError(target, propertyName);
                  ^

CannotInjectValueError: Cannot inject value into "TestController.useCase". Please make sure you setup reflect-metadata properly and you don't use interfaces without service tokens as injection value.
```

imported 'reflect-metadata' on server.ts

I have add on tsconfig.json

```
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"strictPropertyInitialization": false,
```

```
import { UseCase } from './usecase.model'
import { Service } from 'typedi'


@Service()
export class TestUseCase implements UseCase<any, any> {
  async exec() {
    return 'hello'
  }
}
```

but when I try to inject inside a controller:

```
@JsonController()
@Service()
export class TestController {

  @Inject()
  private useCase: TestUseCase;

  @Get('/any')
  async createProducts() {
    return await this.useCase.exec()
  }
}
```